# How to interpret the results from calling top in terminal

Tags: linux, arch-linux, top, linux-terminal

[image: Results From top]

After running `$ top` I've noticed that the white values are always significantly larger than the red, which seems strange, but while running no programs except for firefox quantum, the above image was produced, in which GiB Memory  is impossibly high. Does anyone have any ideas on how to investigate this issue?

I'm running Arch Linux with Gnome3 on a Dell Inspiron 15 L5000 Series dual booted with Windows 8.1 on a partitioned hard drive.